# Plesk Nameserver Not Resolving

Tags: dns, plesk, nameservers

I have a VPS from myhosting.com with Plesk 11.  I've set up dns in windows plenty of times but for the life of me I can't seem to get this working through Plesk.  Here are my settings through Plesk and Godaddy... I asked myhosting about the setup and they said as far as they can see it seems correct but for the life of me the site will not resolve...  Any help would be much appreciated!!

Plesk:

[image: Plesk]

GoDaddy Host Names:

[image: Godaddy Host Names]

GoDaddy Nameserver Settings:

[image: Godaddy NameServer]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Enter your domain name here http://who.godaddy.com/ and in results:

   - Check "status" - should be ACTIVE
   - Check "Name Servers" it should be ns1.v...v.com, ns2.v...v.com
2. Check that ns1.v...v.com or ns2.v...v.com can be resolved by command:

   nslookup ns1.v...v.com

   I suppose that it will be NOT resolved because your NS servers are placed in zone which can be resolved yet.

The easiest way is to use some another DNS servers, maybe GoDaddy or some other DNS hoster.

Or you can make a trick:

1. change domain's DNS servers to GoDaddy DNS servers
2. In GoDaddy's domain management panel add in DNS zone records with: ns1.v...v.com, ns2.v...v.com
3. Wait until you can resolve ns1.v...v.com and ns2.v...v.com - it's about 24 hours.
4. Switch domain's DNS server back to ns1.v...v.com and ns2.v...v.com.
5. Wait until changes will be visible by other DNS servers like Google:

   nslookup ns1.v...v.com 8.8.8.8
6. All should works now.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll try the trick and get back to you... I figured something was "stuck" :P...  nslookup isnt resolving currently for sure... and the name servers show appropriately currently.

Comment: Hah, well it turns out that I didn't do anything wrong... the host had the DNS port blocked in windows firewall by default so this was doomed to fail :P.  Thanks for your suggestion though!